# Recovering a docker swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

We have several docker swarm clusters in production. Each of them has 4-10 nodes. We have 3-5 `manager` nodes in each of them as per the recommendation to meet raft quorum.  These are hosted in EC2 instances in different AWS regions.

Our cluster became unstable due to a recent outage in one of the AWS AZs and since then I'm running this production cluster with just one `manager` which is not recommended.  My attempt to promote other nodes succeeds, but in a few seconds, I lose the cluster and I see the message `The swarm does not have a leader. It's possible that too few managers are online. Make sure more than half of the managers are online.`  Only way to recover the cluster is to reinitialize swarm cluster again on the manager node.  For eg.  `swarm init --force-new-cluster`.

Though the cluster continues to work after this, I see inconsistent node list.  The node I attempted to add remain `down` and I must forcefully leave the swarm and remove the node from manager cluster.  Attempt to remove this node from cluster results in the message `the node you are attempting to remove is a manager`. `docker node inspect <nodeid>` shows its `Role` as `manager` but any cluster level operations on the node fails stating that the node is not a manager.

I can't afford to lose this cluster and recreate as there are live customers who expect high uptime.   It's risky leaving the setup as I don't have sufficient `manager` nodes and any operation related to swarm cluster is leaving the cluster in an inconsistent state.

`dockerd`  logs in `/var/log/syslog` is not very helpful in identifying the root cause. Following is the log snippet I found when I promote another node as `manager`

```
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.576569707Z" level=info msg="dispatcher stopping" method="(*Dispatcher).Stop" module=dispatcher node.id=t2x1wbrgq616fsx6v7ay2euqn
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.576746632Z" level=info msg="dispatcher session dropped, marking node ig3w333ffmkdbff9hz1g58d0f down" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=ig3w333ffmkdbff9hz1g58d0f node.session=c19degio4wtlcfm2xwkjsr7oq
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.576772083Z" level=error msg="failed to remove node" error="rpc error: code = Aborted desc = dispatcher is stopped" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=ig3w333ffmkdbff9hz1g58d0f node.session=c19degio4wtlcfm2xwkjsr7oq
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.576858405Z" level=info msg="dispatcher session dropped, marking node 3zgtdu6meh3ixf8h7vtwpo2ic down" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=3zgtdu6meh3ixf8h7vtwpo2ic node.session=1yqzxseeumz6m8cqy4bfpqq9f
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.576878476Z" level=error msg="failed to remove node" error="rpc error: code = Aborted desc = dispatcher is stopped" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=3zgtdu6meh3ixf8h7vtwpo2ic node.session=1yqzxseeumz6m8cqy4bfpqq9f
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.576986159Z" level=info msg="dispatcher session dropped, marking node bk5mapetwtri0gax5o8zc29k2 down" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=bk5mapetwtri0gax5o8zc29k2 node.session=9ae2u0v2dlyyo8do3tv7e4b8m
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.577008040Z" level=error msg="failed to remove node" error="rpc error: code = Aborted desc = dispatcher is stopped" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=bk5mapetwtri0gax5o8zc29k2 node.session=9ae2u0v2dlyyo8do3tv7e4b8m
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.577097253Z" level=info msg="dispatcher session dropped, marking node znbimzdsduwzzfggl1uno3n9c down" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=znbimzdsduwzzfggl1uno3n9c node.session=xz5xvsnc1tr0eb0p5ytd8eu5s
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.577127094Z" level=error msg="failed to remove node" error="rpc error: code = Aborted desc = dispatcher is stopped" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=znbimzdsduwzzfggl1uno3n9c node.session=xz5xvsnc1tr0eb0p5ytd8eu5s
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.577268958Z" level=info msg="dispatcher session dropped, marking node c6fnnzlrcb59ob0mcpwaf52f7 down" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=c6fnnzlrcb59ob0mcpwaf52f7 node.session=mt8sd2646xgk9lw549ydri43a
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.577326000Z" level=error msg="failed to remove node" error="rpc error: code = Aborted desc = dispatcher is stopped" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=c6fnnzlrcb59ob0mcpwaf52f7 node.session=mt8sd2646xgk9lw549ydri43a
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.577396992Z" level=info msg="dispatcher session dropped, marking node p6r18tf30q6boy5woygvnfnrv down" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=p6r18tf30q6boy5woygvnfnrv node.session=680gvutmvvyf14sy6yjc3sf00
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.577426743Z" level=error msg="failed to remove node" error="rpc error: code = Aborted desc = dispatcher is stopped" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=p6r18tf30q6boy5woygvnfnrv node.session=680gvutmvvyf14sy6yjc3sf00
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.577309389Z" level=info msg="dispatcher session dropped, marking node t2x1wbrgq616fsx6v7ay2euqn down" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=t2x1wbrgq616fsx6v7ay2euqn node.session=dii2khkdxlqvs2ckao7hhin0u
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.577502235Z" level=error msg="failed to remove node" error="rpc error: code = Aborted desc = dispatcher is stopped" method="(*Dispatcher).Session" node.id=t2x1wbrgq616fsx6v7ay2euqn node.session=dii2khkdxlqvs2ckao7hhin0u
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.578248017Z" level=info msg="leadership changed from not yet part of a raft cluster to no cluster leader" module=node node.id=t2x1wbrgq616fsx6v7ay2euqn
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.578520436Z" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=100ms error="rpc error: code = Aborted desc = node must disconnect" module=node/agent node.id=t2x1wbrgq616fsx6v7ay2euqn
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.578593468Z" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: { }" module=node/agent node.id=t2x1wbrgq616fsx6v7ay2euqn
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:12.578634949Z" level=info msg="waiting 77.462294ms before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=t2x1wbrgq616fsx6v7ay2euqn
 dockerd[24061]: time="2021-03-03T05:43:17.656467883Z" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=300ms error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=t2x1wbrgq616fsx6v7ay2euqn
```

This is a 7-node cluster with 3 nodes running v20.10.5 and 4 nodes running v19.03.13 on Ubuntu LTS 18.04. Any pointers to troubleshoot this and recover the cluster is appreciated.